# JSONPath flat structure unable to filter on string

Tags: json, jsonpath

When using JSONPath with the following

```
{
    "tradeID": "12345",
    "version": "1"
}
```

with the expression `$.tradeID[?(@ == '12345')]` nothing is being returned.

However with `$[?(@ == '12345')]` the the expression resolves correctly.

Why? It looks like the filter expression is unable to operate on tradeID at all as its a base leaf?

Answer (score 1):

The expression `$.tradeID[?(@ == '12345')]` says to navigate from root to child element `tradeID` and match values filtered to select only array elements matching `'12345`'.  Since `tradeID` is a simple value instead of an array in your input, this does not match.  If the value of `tradeID` was an array, then it would match.

### Input

```
{
    "tradeID": [ "12345", "67890" ],
    "version": "1"
}
```

### JSONPath

```
$.tradeID[?(@ == '12345')]
```

### Output

```
[
  "12345"
]
```

As you discovered, the expression `$[?(@ == '12345')]` does match.  This expression says to navigate from the root to any of its child elements and select the values, with the values filtered to select only `'12345'`.  However, be aware that if there are other keys in the document mapped to value `'12345`', then it might return more than you expected.

### Input

```
{
    "tradeID": "12345",
    "version": "1",
    "otherID": "12345"
}
```

### JSONPath

```
$[?(@ == '12345')]
```

### Output

```
[
  "12345",
  "12345"
]
```

If the goal is simply to pull the `tradeID`, then no filtering expression is required.

### Input

```
{
    "tradeID": "12345",
    "version": "1",
    "otherID": "12345"
}
```

### JSONPath

```
$.tradeID
```

### Output

```
[
  "12345"
]
```

If the goal is to match a specific document by `tradeID` within an array of multiple documents, then you can select all elements of a top-level array with a filtering expression that matches the desired `tradeID`.

### Input

```
[
    {
        "tradeID": "12345",
        "version": "1"
    },
    {
        "tradeID": "67890",
        "version": "2"
    }
]
```

### JSONPath

```
$.[?(@.tradeID == '12345')]
```

### Output

```
[
  {
    "tradeID": "12345",
    "version": "1"
  }
]
```